# Как сделать ListView с кнопками

Tags: java, android

Как сделать что бы при нажатий на элемент в TextView происходило действие?
Например при нажатий кнопки

Comment: Маловато информации в вопросе для ответа. Если предположить, что вы хотите по нажатию на элемент списка выполнить действие - то, вроде, на ListView можно слушатель нажатий на айтемы повесить. Но советую сразу делать через RecyclerView - оно сильно сложнее, но гораздо гибче.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: `ListView` стоит использовать только для простых списков типа выпадаюших менюшек. Для компоновки посложнее изучайте [`RecyclerView`](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/recyclerview)